# Using Python to upload a single file to sharepoint 403

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to upload a single txt file to Sharepoint using Python and Office365 library. But I keep running into a "403 Client Error: Forbidden for url" even though the app registration has the permission for read,write all. I think I am passing in the wrong folder path. But I am not sure.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
import msal
import requests

client_id = xxxxx
client_secret = xxxxx
tenant_id = xxxxx
site_url = xxxxx



authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority
)

token_response = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=scopes, account=None)
if not token_response:
    token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)

access_token = token_response['access_token']

file_path = 'C:/Users/test/Desktop/test.txt'
file_name = 'test.txt'
folder_server_relative_url = '/sites/Mysite/Shared%20Documents/'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=site_url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id, client_secret)
ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)

with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_server_relative_url)
    ctx.load(target_folder)
    ctx.execute_query()

    file_url = f"{target_folder.properties['ServerRelativeUrl']}/{file_name}"
    upload_url = site_url + f"/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{target_folder.properties['ServerRelativeUrl']}')/Files/Add(url='{file_url}', overwrite=true)"
    
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length': str(os.path.getsize(file_path))
    }
    
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        response = requests.put(upload_url, headers=headers, data=file)
        response.raise_for_status()

print("File uploaded successfully.")
```

Comment: Can provide the response content of the error ? It might give you more precision about what's going wrong. You can do this by printing response.content before response.raise_for_status()